# SSJS - Error API - SSRF detected

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, security-token

When trying to push a request to a specific endpoint (in a kafka topic exactly).
Support team tell me to check for whitelisting SFMC Ip Addresses, it was already done.
This same Request works in Postman (with whitelisted IP).

```
        var payload ={"records":[{"key":"testMG","value":{"metadata":{"attr1":"attr1","date":"2023-04-03T13:23:07.433Z"},"data":{"date2":"2023-04-03T13:23:07.433Z","attr2":"attr2","email":"sun@dakar.sn"}}}]};
        var url = 'https://qa.api.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx';
        var access_token = getAzureToken();
        var bearerToken = "Bearer " + access_token;
        try{      
             var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
             var headerValues = [bearerToken];
             var contentType = 'application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json';
             var  Result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
         } catch(e){
                    Write("<br><br>error -"+Stringify(e));
         }
```

Getting this error.

```
{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.",
"description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n 
Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\n
ExactTarget.Core.Security.SSRF.SSRFException: 
SSRF detected: [https://qa.api.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx] - from ExactTarget.Core\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}
```